# Magento move js scripts in footer from header

Tags: javascript, magento, seo

Google PageSpeed Insights tell me, what I'm need move my js scripts in footer from header and this is improve speed of load my site.

Questions:

1. This is true?
2. And if is true, how me do this in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's not the best idea.
2. Here you can find how to do it + cons and pros: [Move all Javascript includes to before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/355/move-all-javascript-includes-to-before-body) .

Comment: Thanks, I ponder and try it.